# ERROR: local_action is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook

Tags: yaml, ansible

Trying to use ansible to spin up instances on linode. I've pip installed linode-python according to http://docs.ansible.com/linode_module.html

I've also made extra adjustments per http://softwareas.com/ansible-and-linode-what-i-learned-about-controlling-linodes-from-ansible/

The command line:

```
ansible localhost -m linode  -a "api_key=xxx name=test plan=1 distribution=124 datacenter=3 password=xxx state=present"
```

works. Why does this playbook not work?

```
---
- local_action:
     module: linode
     api_key: 'xxx'
     name: quickpic
     plan: 1
     datacenter: 3
     distribution: 124
     password: 'xxx'
     wait: yes
     wait_timeout: 600
     state: present
```

$ ansible-playbook test.yml
*ERROR: local_action is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook*

Comment: RTM: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html

Comment: thanks... others goggling this error will also now know to read the manual.

Comment: I landed here after reading the example [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/linode_module.html). The examples do not include the connection/host part of the playbook with no indication that it was left out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the connection/host part of the playbook. See [Local Playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks) in the documentation.

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create a linode machine
      linode: 
        api_key: 'longStringFromLinodeApi'
        name: linode-test1
        plan: 1
        ...etc
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I think we're getting close. When I run this exactly as you provide I get `ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, test.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 2, column 15

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
    connection: local`

Answer (score 1):

Hah! Thanks Josh! just played with the indents and this works:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create linode machine
      linode: 
        api_key: 'xxx'
        name: test
        plan: 1
        datacenter: 3
        distribution: 124
        password: 'xxx'
        wait: yes
        wait_timeout: 600
        state: present
```

Comment: Ah yes, my bad for an editing fubar. Glad you got it working.